# Client has asked me to create a Search Engine like ASK or Excite. What details do I need?

Tags: search-engine

I am asked to create a Search Engine like ASK or Excite.com. What details will I need to make it possible? What is preferable back-end language? Algorithms? Geographical location will be USA for now.

Please share as much information as you can. 
Thank you

Comment: try Elastic Search you can integrate it with python-django

Comment: How about PHP? or .net? Can it be used to integrate?